# IEEE 754 floating point rounding mode hardware/software

Tags: floating-point, rounding, ieee-754

There are several rounding modes in the IEEE 754 floating point standard, my question is: is the rounding mode selected based on the guard/round/sticky bits or does a programmer specify what mode to use?

Comment: This question is a little broad.  Do you have a specific application in mind?

Comment: I'm making a floating point adder in Logisim (a logic simulator) and after the addition I have to round the result, for example rounding up. What i don't understand is whether this rounding mode is chosen based on the result of the addition or a programmer tells it to round up, down, etc...

Answer (score 2):

The rounding mode is chosen by the programmer. Either the rounding mode is stored in a “control register” inside the FPU, and is changed through a specific (expensive) instruction, or each floating-point instruction has a few bits reserved to indicate what rounding mode it is intended to be executed in.

Either way, the programmer controls the rounding mode that applies each time a floating-point instruction is executed, and the rounding mode influences how the guard/round/sticky bits are interpreted to round the result, not the other way round.